# How can I register a keyboard shortcut that can be used outside of focus using electron?

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, electron

I have an app built in [GitHub's Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).  I need to register a global keyboard shortcut that opens a menu of some kind when pressed.

I'd like to register Ctrl+Alt+V.  A shell menu where the cursor focus is would be ideal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fairly simple to setup a `globalShortcut` in Electron. The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md), but the gist of it is:

```
globalShortcut.register('Ctrl+Alt+v', function() {
    // open menu
});
```

As for a menu, I'm not sure what you mean by "shell menu", however as far as I know Electron has no built in global menu. You would likely use a simple Electron window, and create a menu with CSS.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had read these docs but assumed they needed focus of some sort of app window. Thanks again

Comment: Hi, this works when 1 Electron window is open.  When I open a second Electron window and the second window is in focus, the keyboard event is still passed to the first window and not the second.  Is there a way to send the keyboard event to the active window instead of the window that was opened first?

Comment: To answer the question in my own comment, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763427/electron-does-not-listen-keydown-event
electron-localshortcut allows registering keyboard events to multiple Electron windows that are open at the same time, instead of only the first Electron window that is open