# Electron does not listen keydown event

Tags: javascript, electron

I am a backend developer who got a little project to fix it.
So my boss gives me an electron project which runs on touch devices.

I know that I can listen any key events in Javascript if I use the `document` object, but in electron it does not work, it says the `docuemnt cannot be found`.

So implemented this when I or other support guy press the F12 button then the dev tools be rendered out in the electron app.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    'web-preferences': {'web-security': false}
  });

  mainWindow.onkeydown = function (e) {
    console.log("Key down");
    if (e.which === 123) {
      console.log("Key is F12");
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
  };
```

But this code is not working to me. I have no idea how I can listen the F12 button is pressed.

Unfortunately I cannot render out button to the UI which can show the devtools. Because of the customers mustn't press it.

Sometimes I need to see the realtime console tab in devtools on the device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [known issue in Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1334) ( which has lately been marked as `wontfix` ) that prevents the usual approach to catch key events using the traditional JS approach.

There also is a small library called [electron-localshortcut](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut) that circumvents this issue by hijacking the Electron global shortcuts API when the window is active.

Use like this in your main.js:

```
const electronLocalshortcut = require('electron-localshortcut');
electronLocalshortcut.register(mainWindow, 'F12', () => {
    // Open DevTools
});
```

Comment: The [documentation of the accelerators](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/accelerator.md) in Electron does not say exactly what they are based on, but keypress is implied.

Comment: Thanks, I tried registering keyboard events with globalShortcut, but that only worked for the first Electron window that was open, it did not work for multiple windows if they were open at the same time.  electron-localshortcut works for multiple windows open at the same time

Comment: You will have to register your shortcuts for each window, the localShortcut library will then take care of forwarding the respective shortcut to the currently active window.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional libraries you can use "globalShortcut" of electron

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut } = require("electron");
globalShortcut.register("CmdOrCtrl+F12", () => {
  mainWindow.isFocused() && mainWindow.webContents.toggleDevTools();
});
```

I think F12 is preserved so I use ctrl+f12 which is not far off

Comment: it works for winda and macos thank you, no key event conflicts and no needed install other libraries 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) to add global short cut, because it can be installed through node and could bypass the problem of electron mentioned in the accepted answer.

A code example in the render process would be:

```
var Mousetrap = require('mousetrap');
Mousetrap.bind('4', function() { console.log('4'); });
```